# Pure CSS parallax with actual interactive content as 'background'?

Tags: css, parallax, interactive

I need to achieve a parallax effect where an assortment of things are the "background" layer, like videos, canvases or other interactive things, while walls of text scroll by, and when those texts "end" I need to be able to scroll to the next slide, holding, again, any number of things as its 'background'. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4TVG.jpg for a simple reference (smiley = interactive content, rectangle = wall of text).

Is that something I can do with pure CSS? Or do I need to resort to a library like ScrollMagic for this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `background-attachment: fixed;`

In essence, the background is "fixed" to the element and when it scrolls up, so does your image.

[More info](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-attachment/)

**UPDATE:** Position: absolute your element to your parent element.

**UPDATE2:** Okay, [here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) and [here](https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw) looks promising. Creating custom fiddle.

**UPDATE3** Rough draft of [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gykt45bb/2/). Main logic:

```
.depth-1 {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 10px;
}

.depth-2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.depth-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: blue;
}

.depth-3 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

.dont-move {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="depth-1">
  <div class="depth-2">
    <div class="depth-3">
      <div class="depth-4">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dont-move">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="depth-1">
  <div class="depth-2">
    <div class="depth-3">
      <div class="depth-4">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dont-move">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE4:** Updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gykt45bb/3/), additional formatting. The main problem is that it won't "clear" that last section before scrolling the new section.

Comment: But the "background" here can be like, an iframe, a video, anything. It's not a background image